# GroundOverlay bounds changing after creation

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently defining multiple GroundOverlays in a MapFragment. I'm creating each GroundOverlay by LatLngBounds and for the most part everything aligns; however, some of the GroundOverlays end up slightly off.

If I log the bounds after creation, they match my expectations. The second time I log them, they're slightly off.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(point1_lat, point1_lon), new LatLng(point2_lat, point2_lon));

Log.d(TAG, "Bounds southwest: " + bounds.southwest.latitude + ", " + bounds.southwest.longitude);
Log.d(TAG, "Bounds northeast: " + bounds.northeast.latitude + ", " + bounds.northeast.longitude);

GroundOverlay groundOverlay = getMap().addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(bitmapDescriptor)
                        .positionFromBounds(bounds)
                    );

Log.d(TAG, "southwest: " + groundOverlay.getBounds().southwest.latitude + ", " + groundOverlay.getBounds().southwest.longitude);
Log.d(TAG, "northeast: " + groundOverlay.getBounds().northeast.latitude + ", " + groundOverlay.getBounds().northeast.longitude);
```

Any ideas why the GroundOverlay creation would make the latitude and longitude change?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the images are being resized to make sure the width/height have lengths that are a power of 2. From the docs...

> **Note**: When the image is added to the map it will be converted to an image with sides that are powers of two. You can avoid this conversion by using an original image with dimensions that are powers of two — for example, 128x512 or 1024x1024.

Andy.